# It always use seq scan on column in Postgresql cause performance issue

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

We use the postgresql and have a table, such as table1. The are total 500k data in the table and 400k are state in "A". We have a SQL to filter the data and there is condition base on the state. The SQL execute about 1min. Because for the state condition to filter 'A' use seq scan take much time, if remove this condition, the sql could be finished in secs. I also tried "select * from table1 where state = 'A'". It also used seq scan and it's very slow. For other state it use index scan and very fast.

I have read a said if the data more than 10% of table it will use the seq scan directly. So I want ask for this situation how to optimize the SQL to make it execute fast.

Comment: "We have a SQL to filter the data" How do you filter?

Comment: When you say the sql statement finishes in seconds, I think you do not account for the time necessary to pull the entire data to your client. Frankly, why would you have a query pull such amount of data. Explain your use case. In both filtered and unfiltered a full read of the entire data is necessary.

Comment: The entire SQL is like select * from table1 where state in (C, D) or (state in (A,B) and duedate< now()). The SQL is intend to find the data which state in C or D or the data is overdue. The overdue column is base on due date to calculate and state could be in A or B. We need this to join other table. The target condition is dynamic from front end, which mean user could select what they want. The problem is even select * from table1 where state = 'A' is very slow, because the data number cause it use seq scan.

Comment: This is way too vague.  Please show the text of each query and the EXPLAIN (ANALYZE,  BUFFERS) for them.

Comment: Well, if you are looking for surface less than now, adding an index on duedate will probably cut on the 400,000 rows

Answer (score 0):

if 400000 of 500000 rows of a table have `state = 'A'`, using an index scan will be more expensive than a sequential scan.  Reading the index is unnecessary extra work in that case, because you have to read practically the whole table anyway.

It is normal that such a query takes longer, because it has more work to do. If it takes excessively long, the problem may be your client that has trouble digesting the many result rows (try to see the execution time on the server with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)`).

The only ways to make such a query faster is to get faster storage or to load the whole table into RAM, e.g. by using the `pg_prewarm` extension.